# Has Monero published a definitive, concise threat model?

Tags: security, research

[I2P's threat model](https://geti2p.net/en/docs/how/threat-model) consolidates various aspects of garlic/onion [threat modeling](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Threat_Modeling) into one document. Does Monero have a similar document and, if so, where can this document be found?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is none.

This is an excellent opportunity for a new contributor with knowledge of threat modelling :)